# How to distribute trivial tasks to workes using MPI

Tags: mpi

I'm trying to teach myself some simple MPI. As an exercise I thought I'd try and distribute a simple task over some workers. The task as outlined below is simply to hold the CPU for some predetermined time. The goal of the program is to verify that a worker asks for new work as soon as it is finished with it's current task, and conversely that it does not wait for other workers in order to do so.

For three CPUs (one manager and two workers) expected output from the below program is something like

```
worker #1 waited for 1 seconds
worker #2 waited for 1 seconds
worker #1 waited for 1 seconds
worker #1 waited for 1 seconds
...
worker #2 waited for 5 seconds
worker #1 waited for 1 seconds
worker #2 waited for 1 seconds
...
```

However, in the current implementation, the program never gets past the first two output lines. I'm thinking this is because the workers does not correctly communicate to the manager that that they have finished their tasks, and therefore are never given their next tasks.

Any ideas where it goes wrong?

```
#include <iostream>
#include <mpi.h>
#include <windows.h>           

using namespace std;

void task(int waittime, int worldrank) {
    Sleep(waittime); // use sleep for unix systems
    cout << "worker #" << worldrank << " waited for " << waittime << " seconds" << endl;
}

int main()
{

    int waittimes[] = { 1,1,5,1,1,1,1,1,1,1,1,1,1 };
    int nwaits = sizeof(waittimes) / sizeof(int);

    MPI_Init(NULL, NULL);

    int worldrank, worldsize;
    MPI_Comm_rank(MPI_COMM_WORLD, &worldrank);
    MPI_Comm_size(MPI_COMM_WORLD, &worldsize);

    MPI_Status status;

    int ready = 0;
    
    if (worldrank == 0)
    {

        for (int k = 0; k < nwaits; k++)
        {

            MPI_Recv(&ready, 1, MPI_INT, MPI_ANY_SOURCE, MPI_ANY_TAG, MPI_COMM_WORLD, &status);

            MPI_Send(&waittimes[k], 1, MPI_INT, status.MPI_SOURCE, 0, MPI_COMM_WORLD);

        }

    }

    else
    {

        int waittime;

        ready = 1;

        MPI_Send(&ready, 1, MPI_INT, 0, 0, MPI_COMM_WORLD);

        MPI_Recv(&waittime, 1, MPI_INT, 0, 0, MPI_COMM_WORLD, &status);

        task(waittime,worldrank);
        
    }

    MPI_Finalize();

    return 0;
}
```

Comment: _"I'm thinking this is because the workers does not correctly communicate to the manager that that they have finished their tasks, and therefore are never given their next tasks. Any ideas where it goes wrong?"_ I think you exactly described what goes wrong. So, you basically answered your question.

Comment: Well, that's nice and all, but isn't that what this part is supposed to do: ```MPI_Send(&ready, 1, MPI_INT, 0, 0, MPI_COMM_WORLD);``` ? Reporting to the manager that they finished their task that is.

Comment: The manager needs to use `Isend/Irecv` because otherwise it's waiting for all the workers *in sequence* rather than in parallel.

Comment: you should always include your `mpirun` command line. Whatif `worldsize -1 != nwaits`?

Comment: The problem is that each worker performs only one task. What if you have 2 workers and 10 tasks? Only 2 tasks are accomplished by workers then and the root/manager process will never end. Workers need to be able to receive multiple task (and, at the end, some stopping command).